# Read an xls file as a multidimensional array using phpexcel

Tags: php, cakephp, phpexcel

I want to retrieve this xls file in PHP as an array:

[image]

I tried this code:

```
App::import('Vendor', 'PHPExcel', array('file' => 'PHPExcel.php'));
$excelFile = DAY_DIR."/data.xlsx";

$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($excelFile);

//Itrating through all the sheets in the excel workbook and storing the array data
foreach ($objPHPExcel->getWorksheetIterator() as $worksheet) {
    $arrayData[$worksheet->getTitle()] = $worksheet->toArray();
}

pr($arrayData);
```

I want to read it as a multidimension array but it returns this:
[image]

Please suggest how can I achieve it.

Comment: What output or error did you get using your code?

Comment: There is no error , I just want output in nested way .

Comment: My question is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19722542/change-excel-data-into-a-multidimensional-array

Comment: Please share the results of your code.

Comment: Its in above screen shot

Comment: You might want to also share what you expect your output to look like. "Multidimensional" is pretty generic.

Comment: hi @GregSchmidt  , please see this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19722542/change-excel-data-into-a-multidimensional-array

Comment: @GregSchmidt , in this question , he was asking for same thing and he also give output he want. I tried solution he provided but I think its wrong.

Comment: His solution is particular to his data. Your data, while also being from Excel, has a different format (he had 6 columns, you apparently have 12, though only 6 are shown). So, his solution is not going to directly work for you.